# Im having trouble sending a string value to mysql using a stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql

I am attempting to send the value of string through a callablestatement to a mysql database. It works when i enter a string manually into my statement in replace for the variable but i need to call the string from another class.

This is my stored procedure, it works.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`jbreen`@`%` PROCEDURE `getlocation`(IN location VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT locationname, addressone, addresstwo FROM Locations_AL
WHERE locationname = location;
END
```

In my first class the string its retrieved from a combo box:

```
String locations = cb_Location.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

In my second class the string is entered into the statement like this:

```
String sql = "{CALL getlocation(?)}";
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
stmt.setString(1, MainActivity.locations);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

No rows are returned when this is executed. I attempted adding '' before and after the string as i thought this could be the case but no luck...

Comment: Most probably this is a right code and u don't have an issue with the code that u have shared.... So I think u should share the code on how u are getting the column values by reading the rs

Comment: This may help you:  "SELECT locationname, addressone, addresstwo FROM Locations_AL WHERE locationname = '" + location + "';"